# Best way to give Location information to a service

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I have searched quite a bit and I'm not totally clueless. I have implemented a temporary solution on my end but was wondering if there is a better approach out there.

I have an app that sends a person's location after every 60 seconds to a server. On my dashboard (the main screen that will go to **onPause** after application starts), I have registered a **LocationManager** with the following code:

```
service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!enabled)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            service.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 50, this);

            Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            // Initialize the location fields
            if (location != null)
            {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("Location: ", "No update received");
            }
        }
```

However, as I mentioned, this activity will be minimized by the user (by pressing the home button). There is a service that gets called every 60 seconds by an AlarmManager. That service accesses static variables from the Dashboard Activity (lat, lon) and sends it to the server.

My question:

**If the activity goes onPause, will the requestLocationUpdates function stop? Or will it keep working?**

If it keeps working, it will keep updating the two lat and lon static String objects and the service will keep getting updated values. If they stop, the service will keep getting the same old values again and again.

Also, is there a better way to approach this problem? Using a mix of GPS Provider and Network Provider? (I need fairly accurate values).

**EDIT**

Here's my Alarm. This code is inside **Login** Activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(con, LocationPoller.class);
                i.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_INTENT, new Intent(con,
                        Login.class));
                i.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_PROVIDER,
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                gps = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 0, i, 0);
                gps.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),
                        10 * 1000, pi);
                Log.d("Service: ",
                        "GPS Service started and scheduled with AlarmManager");
```

Here's my receiver (also within Login activity)

```
private class ReceiveMessages extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Location loc = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(
                    LocationPoller.EXTRA_LOCATION);

            String msg;

            if (loc == null)
            {
                msg = intent.getStringExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR);
            }
            else
            {
                msg = loc.toString();
            }

            if (msg == null)
            {
                msg = "Invalid broadcast received!";
            }

            Log.d("GPS Broadcast: ", msg);
        }
    }
```

Nothing's happening :s Not getting anything on logcat which means the broadcast isn't being received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When activity goes on pause, all registered listeners will stop. Better way to implement this is, alarm manager sent a broadcast every 60 seconds, this broadcast receiver starts a service and this service will request a location on Wakeful thread, once location information is retrieved, update the location on server.

There is an Open source library available with an example (courtesy CommonsWare), please refer below link. Its under Apache 2.0 license

[Location Polling Library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll)

Please find my sample project using above library. I have modified few things in the above library and created my own version.

[Location Polling Demo Application](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/69417269/LocationPoolerDemo.zip)

Comment: That example is way to complex for a task as trivial as this.

Comment: @Asim - I assume you want to continuously getting location and updating to the server. If that is the case, then you need this complexity. For example, if phone is in sleeping mode and you want to upload the location information. In order to do so, you need to acquire wake lock, get and upload location and then release the wake lock. If your need is just get and update location when activity is in foreground, then you can achieve this by starting a service from your activity which fetch the location and update it to server

Comment: OK I've imported the library. I'm a bit confused now (totally new to BroadcastReceiver). I'm starting the Alarm on the login screen. That screen goes into onResume (or whatever) when the user logs in (the user lands on the dashboard).
Which activity should the RECEIVER be in? Moreover, my dashboard activity is already using a receiver for another task.. How do I differentiate between the multiple broadcasts? I know intents.. But the starting intent for this broadcast is Intent(Login, Dashboard), but how can I use this in my Dashboard activity?

Sorry if this is all very confusing :)

Comment: Your AlarmManager should use PendingIntent.getBroadcast(). So when alarm goes off, then it will send a broadcast to your receiver defined in PendingIntent

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27460/discussion-between-asim-and-amit)

Comment: @Asim - I have updated my answer and attached a demo application with some modification in library, please use it at your own risk

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer correct. Thanks for ALL the help. Wish I had someone like you on Skype or something :D

Your app works fine on my phone, but copying ur code (properly, and fixing errors) into my project returns the same result - no broadcasts.

I'm looking into it and will hopefully get to the bottom of it.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, what are these? In your LocationPoller.java, there are these static Strings that say EXTRA_ERROR = com.example.locationpoolerdemo.location.EXTRA_ERROR etc.

What is the .location. here? I have changed the package name to mine but its still not working. Same goes for the WakefulIntentService.java where a similar reference is made.

Comment: There are static variable which will be sent as extras in Intent and compared in LocationReceivers for erros

Comment: Did you added BroadcastReceivers and Services in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes. Please check the chat, I have added details there. I've to leave for home in a bit. I hope you're able to help me fix this :(